# Qemu mouse movement speed

Tags: qemu

Is there a way to increase the mouse movement speed in qemu? Currently, the mouse in the guest OS is horrible slow even when max speed is set in guest OS.

This is the QEMU startup command:

```
QEMU_AUDIO_DRV=alsa qemu-system-i386 -localtime -m 128 -hda win98.img -cdrom /dev/cdrom -cpu pentium2 -no-hpet -device adlib -device ne2k_pci,netdev=network0 -netdev bridge,br=br0,id=network0
```

Comment: I am quite sure, you don't have **mouse** trouble, but **graphics** trouble. Try using the vmvga virtual graphics card and install the vmvga driver in Win98

Comment: So the cirrus driver is slow or what?

Comment: Everything else renders fast running at 1024x768x24 bbp. And -vga std did not help